# Prove $\forall$ graphs, $\alpha(G) \ge \frac{n}{\Delta(G)+1}$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove $\forall$ graphs, $\alpha(G) \ge \frac{n}{\Delta(G)+1}$

where $\alpha(G) :=$ maximum independent set;
$\Delta(G) :=$ is the maximum degree of any vertex and $n$ is the total number of vertices.

So I know that $\alpha(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$ have an "inverse" relationship with eachother. i.e. $\alpha(G) = n \implies \Delta(G) = 0$ and $\alpha(G) = 1 \implies \Delta(G) = n - 1$

I don't think an induction proof is necessary but I haven't had luck with rearranging the inequality to get some result to 'fall out'

Comment: Given [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679595/26306) in this topic, I am quite astonished that you can't do it yourself. In particular, this inequality is actually weaker, namely $\Delta(G) \geq \deg(v)$ for any $v \in V$.

Comment: @dtldarek I did that problem inductively, this one I am trying to do without induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take a maximal independent set, and for each vertex in that independent set put a pigeon on that vertex and each of its up top $\Delta(G)$ neighbours, we distribute at most $\alpha(G)(\Delta(G)+1)$ pigeons. If this number is $<n$, there exists a vertex without a pigeon on it; adding this vertex produces a larger independent set - contradiction. Therefore $\alpha(G)(\Delta(G)+1)\ge n$.

Comment: Sorry wdym by putting a pigeon on its up top Δ(G) neighbors?